# ng-hide not triggering, maybe something to do with ng-view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, ng-hide

i've got this angular website which works using angular routing. It has a login and on that page i want to hide the header. I've found on other stackoverflow pages that the best way to do this is to use ng-if or ng-hide. however these don't seem to be triggering. There is some dutch in there so just ignore that

```
<nav ng-hide="isLogin()" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img alt="Brand" src="../resources/calendar.png"></a></div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="./taken">Taken</a></li>
      <li><a href="./hulpaanvragers">Hulp aanvragers</a></li>
      <li><a href="./vrijwilligers">Vrijwilligers</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li><a href="./login" ng-click="logout()">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

$scope.isLogin = function(){
    console.log($location.path() == '/login');
    return $location.path() == '/login';
};
```

[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUbng.png)
note how nothing is printed in the console(random text is something else) even tough in their is a console.log() in the isLogin() function

the isLogin() function is located in the logincontroller which is referenced in the app.config() function for the route "/login"

Comment: What is your expected outcome? You want : 1) hide header, after login? 2) fix capability to log in the function?

Comment: i expect the header to be hidden and their to be "/login" logged to the console

Comment: if you use a function to return the value of hide/show the header, this will result in the digest cycle running much more than needed. I will add some code for a better solution.

Comment: thanks, i also tried putting the code directly into the ng-hide but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the reason why ng-hide wasn't working
it was because the navbar wasn't part of ng-view which contained the controller

i was unaware of the fact that the navbar was located outside of the scope of ng-view

i fixed it by adding an extra controller that envelops the entire body

edit*

changed the solution didn't add an extra controller but added the variable to rootscope and rootscope has access to the entire page

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/tlombrana22/pen/QEWwpb?editors=1010), I would recommend doing something different. But based on the given above code this is one way to go about it. The timeout is for example purposes, this might be set from loggin in response success/fail.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

ExampleController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];

function ExampleController($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.hideNav = false;
  $scope.loggedIn = function() {
    //this could also be set in the view.
    $scope.hideNav = true;
  }

  $scope.logOut = function() {
    $scope.hideNav = false;
  }

  $scope.$watch('hideNav', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal == true) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.hideNav = false;
      }, 10000);
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-app="app">
  <nav ng-hide="hideNav" class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
          <img alt="Brand" src="../resources/calendar.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="./taken">Taken</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./hulpaanvragers">Hulp aanvragers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./vrijwilligers">Vrijwilligers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="loggedIn()">log in</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="logOut()">logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```